# Universal $C^*$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

It is known that the $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal U$ generated by bilateral shift $\ell^2 (\mathbb Z) \ni e_k \mapsto e_{k+1} \in \ell ^2(\mathbb Z)$, is a universal $C^*$ algebra generated by unitary: for every $a$ in a $C^*$-algebra $A$ which satisfies $aa^*=a^*a=\mathbb 1$ there is a $C^*$-algebra morphism $\mathcal U\rightarrow C^*(a)$.

It isn't true, though, in general - if we consider some generators $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ which satisfies relations expressed with noncommutative polynomial in $2n$ variables $p$: $p(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_1^*,\dots,x_n^*)=0$, there may not be any $C^*$-algebra with above universal property.

Is there any nice condition on $p$ which would say when such $C^*$-algebra exists? What if we consider more polynomials, not just one?

Comment: Answers (and references to further details) can be found in the answers to this MathOverflow question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/151809/6999

Comment: Thank You for Your comment. I've seen that thread, but either i am blind and missing something, or there isn't answer to my question. I haven't found answer in those references either, but this time reason may be that i didn't understand them.

Comment: I think the moral of the story is that it's a messy business without any particularly clean answers, though Chapter 3 of Loring's *Lifting solutions to perturbing problems in $C^\ast$-algebras* probably comes fairly close? In terms of your immediate question, the most immediate thing you need is for your polynomial relations to imply universal upper bounds on the norms of your generators, e.g., the relations $aa^\ast = a^\ast a = 1$ imply $\|a\| \leq 1$ and $\|a^\ast\| \leq 1$.